# How to get the currently active configuration in a detox test

Tags: react-native, detox

In the [docs](https://github.com/wix/detox/blob/master/docs/Introduction.GettingStarted.md#3-add-detox-config-to-packagejson) it is described how to add multiple detox configs to package.json

When I run the tests with `detox --configuration someconfig`, how do I find out the `someconfig` parameter in my tests (in `someTestSuite.spec.js`)?

Use case: in a test I want to set username and password textinputs based on the config, eg.

```
await getUNameTextInput().typeText('someUsernameBasedOnConfig');
```

Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure this is possible right now. What is your usecase?

Comment: we have multiple build configs, each connecting to a different server. I want to write a test that checks that user can connect to the server. So if I run the test with a debug ipa I'd like it to use user credentials for the debug server, and use credentials for release server when running the release ipa. So I need to know the config in order to know what credentials to use.

Comment: Sounds useful to have. Please open an issue on the GitHub page and link to this question. Thanks

Comment: here's the GH issue: https://github.com/wix/detox/issues/634

Comment: Not sure you're going the right direction. Configuration will not be available for your client code, only inside the tester code in node. If you want to run different client code per config try using react-native-repackager (it is supported natively in RN54)

Comment: @Rotemmiz Yes, but what if they want to configure different mocks for each configuration?

Comment: Different server mocks?

Comment: Is this possible currently? If so, we can close the issue.

Comment: Per-config differing mock

Comment: The answer differs if you want different server mock or client mock.

Comment: I'll compile a full answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167288/discussion-between-rotemmiz-and-leo-natan).

Comment: what I am after: in a test, there is a username and password textfield, and I just need to know, based on config, what text I should insert into the textfields, eg.: `await getUNameTextInput().typeText('someUsernameBasedOnConfig');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a non official way of accessing the configuration name, and it may change in the future:

```
const argparse = require('detox/src/utils/argparse');
const configurationName = argparse.getArgValue('configuration');
```